# How to get the temp unpack directory of a Node-Webkit application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, webkit, node-webkit

Using,

```
var nwPath = process.execPath;
var nwDir = path.dirname(nwPath);
console.log(nwDir);
```

in a Node-Webkit application would give me something like:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp
```

What would give me the directory from within the Node-Webkit application runs the html files from?

Like,

```
C:/Users/USERNAME/AppData/Local/Temp/nw6860_18341/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In NW you can just use `process.cwd()`